# SQL Server Insert based of additional query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL server is it possible to to a mass insert based on a sub query, Essentially I'm trying to do this.

```
Insert into ProductExtra (ProductID,ExtraID) 
VALUES 
(Select ProductID From ProductSKU 
JOIN Product on ProductSKU.ProductID = Product.ID
Where ItemType = 'fire grate' ), 10739
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - but then you must not use the `VALUES` keyword, but this syntax (just a `SELECT`, with columns and fixed values defined in its list of selected columns) instead:

```
INSERT INTO ProductExtra (ProductID, ExtraID) 
   SELECT ProductID, 10739
   FROM ProductSKU 
   JOIN Product ON ProductSKU.ProductID = Product.ID
   WHERE ItemType = 'fire grate'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO ProductExtra (ProductID, ExtraID) 
Select   ProductID, 10739 ExtraID
From     ProductSKU 
         INNER JOIN Product 
              ON ProductSKU.ProductID = Product.ID
Where ItemType = 'fire grate'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
INSERT INTO ProductExtra (ProductID,ExtraID) 
Select ProductID,10739 From ProductSKU 
JOIN Product on ProductSKU.ProductID = Product.ID
Where ItemType = 'fire grate'
```